# Money clip bottle opener US 6851147 B2

Tags: patentability, us6851147, us1267052

How come this patent was granted , when the same/similar item have a patent in 1914 # US1267052??

Answer (score 1):

That patent was known to the applicant who, in turn, made it known to the examiner in an IDS filed with the application. It did not make the examiner's top 5 or 6 similar things.

Edit

To add more meat to this answer, the newer patent claims a money clip where the **bend** itself is the bottle opener. The older patent does not teach that. Yes they are both bottle opener/money clips but create that combination in distinct ways.

From IDS seen in PAIR

[image]